Superfluous letters
In Vayikra 19:18, we have the famous statement "וְאָֽהַבְתָּ֥ לְרֵעֲךָ֖ כָּמ֑וֹךָ".
I was curious about the leading lamed before rei-echa. According to the Ibn Ezra, it has a particular meaning and allows the phrase to mean something different from how others might understand it. But he refers to other commentators who see it as "superfluous" (שהלמ״ד נוסף) and the meaning should be understood as if the lamed had no impact.
But if no letter in the Torah is extra, how can there be any understanding in which we simply ignore a letter as extra?

Can you identify any commentary that says it's superfluous?

Rashi also says letters are extra occasionally. ואת כל אשר יעשה להם ועבדו, and לכל כלי המשכן, and some others

@DoubleAA the Chizkuni writes that the lamed ״‎בו יתרה but the Ibn Ezra says "רבים " so I assume that there are others.

It's much more powerful to ask from a source that claims directly the letter is extra. As is Ibn Ezra may be arguing at a straw-man.

The other option would be to insert the word את. The letter ל is only half as long. There’s no problem here.

Concerning seemingly extra letters, every case needs to be looked at individually to figure out why it's not extra.
In this case the Ramban in Vakikra 19:18 answers, and says the following:

ויתכן בעבור שלא אמר "ואהבת את רעך כמוך" והשוה אותם במלת "לרעך" וכן ואהבת לו כמוך (ויקרא י״ט:ל״ד) דגר שיהיה פירושו להשוות אהבת שניהם בדעתו כי פעמים שיאהב אדם את רעהו בדברים ידועים להטיבו בעושר ולא בחכמה וכיוצא בזה ואם יהיה אוהבו בכל יחפוץ שיזכה רעהו האהוב לו בעושר ובנכסים וכבוד ובדעת ובחכמה ולא שישוה אליו אבל יהיה חפץ בלבו לעולם שיהיה הוא יותר ממנו בכל טובה ויצוה הכתוב שלא תהיה פחיתות הקנאה הזאת בלבו אבל יאהב ברבות הטובה לחבירו כאשר אדם עושה לנפשו ולא יתן שיעורין באהבה ועל כן אמר ביהונתן (שמואל א כ יז) כי אהבת נפשו אהבו בעבור שהסיר מדת הקנאה מלבו ואמר (שם כג יז) ואתה תמלוך על ישראל וגו' וענין הנקימה והנטירה כבר פירשוהו רבותינו (תו"כ קדושים ד י יא) שהוא בדבר שאין בו חיוב ממון השאילני מגלך השאילני קרדומך כי בדבר שנתחייב לו חברו ממון כגון בנזיקין וכיוצא בהן אינו מחוייב להניח לו אבל יתבענו בב"ד וישולם ממנו מפסוק כאשר עשה כן יעשה לו (ויקרא כ״ד:י״ט) והוא מעצמו חייב לשלם כאשר ישלם מה שלוה או מה שגזל וכל שכן בענין נפש שיהיה נוקם ונוטר לו עד שיגאל דמי אחיו מידו על פי בית דין המורים במשפטי התורה:

"And perhaps, because it does not say "Love your neighbor as yourself" but instead equates them with the word "to your neighbor," and similarly "and you shall love him as yourself" (Vayikra 19:34) regarding the stranger, the intention is to equalize the love of both in one's mind. For sometimes a person loves their neighbor in specific matters, benefiting them with wealth but not with wisdom, and so on. And if they love them in everything, they will desire for their beloved neighbor to attain wealth, assets, honor, and wisdom, but not to be equal to them. Instead, they will always wish in their heart to be greater than their neighbor in every good thing. The Torah commands that this deficiency of jealousy should not exist in their heart, but rather, they should love the increase of good for their friend as a person does for themselves, without setting limits to the love. Therefore, it says about Yonatan (Samuel Aleph 20:17) that he loved him as his own soul, because he removed the attribute of jealousy from his heart. And it says (ibid. 23:17), "You will reign over Israel," etc. The matter of vengeance and bearing a grudge has already been explained by our Sages (Sifra Kedoshim 4:10-11) as concerning matters without financial obligation: "Lend me your sickle," "Lend me your hatchet." For in matters where one's friend owes them money, such as damages and similar cases, one is not obligated to forgive but can demand it in court and it will be repaid to them, as it says, "As he has done, so shall it be done to him" (Vayikra 24:19). One is personally obligated to repay, just as they repay a loan or something they stole. All the more so in the matter of life, where one will take vengeance and bear a grudge until the blood of their brother is avenged by the court following the judgments of the Torah."

except that the Ibn Ezra (as evidenced by the Chizkuni) says that there are many who claim that the letter IS extra.

If we look at the Ibn Ezra he says, על דעת רבים שהלמ״ד נוסף כלמ״ד לאבנר ועל דעתי שהוא כמשמעו שיאהב הטוב לחברו כמו לנפשו, and this is what he says , "some think the lamed is extra, and על דעתי, my opinion is (not like that) and we should take it literally that one should love that which is good for one’s neighbor as he does for himself." With reagrds to the Chizkuni he does give a peshat as to why its not extra, ‎ אינו אומר ואהבת רעך כמוך. דאי אפשר לעשות כן אלא לרעך, פירוש ואהבת לעשות לו טובה כמו שאתה אוהב שיעשה הוא לך. דעלך סני לחברך לא תעביד. וכן תפרש גבי והגר הגר אתכם ואהבת לו כמוך.

What I'm trying to say is that even though they say there is a possibility of an extra lamed, there is always an answer saying how it's not extra, but its still a question as to how they can raise a possibility of an extra letter (even though they themselves give an answer!)

but if the Ibn Ezra is right, that there are rabim who say it is extra, then he seems to believe that there are those who see it as extra and unexplained.

It seems that without lamed we are talking about different  love, like Yitzchak for Eisav or Yaakov for Rachel?
